# SQL - Self Join to find two label with a release in common with a third label

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin, self-join, musicbrainz

I'm using PostgreSQL and PgAdmin 4 and I'm working with MusicBrainz database.
I need to find the couples of label that have never released a release in common, but that they both have released a release with a third label (the same label for both).

In the database there are these tables:
label (id, name..) id is primary key.
release_label (id, release, label) id is primary key and label foreign key.

I've tried with self join but it is not working:

```
SELECT l1.name as label_1 , l2.name as label_2
FROM release_label as r1 INNER JOIN label as l1 ON r1.label=l1.id, label as l2
INNER JOIN (release_label as r2 LEFT JOIN release_label as r3
ON r3.label=r2.label)ON r2.label=l2.id WHERE r1.release != r2.release 
AND r1.label!= r3.label AND r1.release=r3.release
GROUP BY label_1,label_2 ORDER BY label_1,label_2
```

Thanks in advice.

Comment: Some sample data would be helpful, and also consider making your problem more minimal than it currently is (if that could still get your point across).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Actually these tables are full of datas. Label contains a lot of IDs and names and for each name, in release_label there are one or more corrispondence with another label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query gets pairs of labels that have never released anything in common:

```
select l1.id as id1, l2.id as id2
from label l1 cross join
     label l2 left join
     release_label rl1 
     on l1.id = rl1.label left join
     release_label rl2
     on l2.id = rl2.label and rl2.release = rl1.release
where rl1.label is null and l1.id < l2.id;
```

Now, you want a third label that has released with both . . .

```
select ll.*, rl3_1.label as in_common
from (select l1.id as id1, l2.id as id2
      from label l1 cross join
           label l2 left join
           release_label rl1 
           on l1.id = rl1.label left join
           release_label rl2
           on l2.id = rl2.label and rl2.release = rl1.release
      where rl1.label is null and l1.id < l2.id
     ) ll join
     release_label rl1
     on rl1.label = ll.id1 join
     release_label rl2
     on rl2.label = ll.id2 join
     release_label rl3_1
     on rl3_1.release = rl1.release join 
     release_label rl3_2
     on rl3_2.release = rl2.release and
        rl3_2.label = rl3_1.label;
```

EDIT:

An alternative method might be simpler:

```
select l1.id, l2.id, l3.id as in_common_id
from label l1 join
     label l2
     on l1.id < l2.id join
     label l3
     on l1.id <> l3.id and l2.id <> l3.id
where -- have no releases in common
      not exists (select 1
                  from release_label rl1 join
                       release_label rl2
                       on rl1.release = rl2.release
                  where rl1.label = l1.id and rl2.label = l2.id
                 ) and
      -- l1 has a release with l3
      exists (select 1
              from release_label rl1 join
                   release_label rl3
                   on rl1.release = rl3.release
                  where rl1.label = l1.id and rl3.label = l3.id
             ) and
      -- l2 has a release with l3
      exists (select 1
              from release_label rl2 join
                   release_label rl3
                   on rl2.release = rl3.release
                  where rl2.label = l2.id and rl3.label = l3.id
             );
```

The `from` clause generates all candidate trips of labels.  The `exists` checks the three conditions you want to check.  This is the version that I would use, because I think the logic is much easier to follow.

In either of these queries, you can (of course) use `select distinct` on the first two ids to just get the pairs you are looking for.